# Bootstrap responsive CSS navbar not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the navbar HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #967BB6;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">Site</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a class="navigate" href="{% url 'profile' request.user.username %}">My Profile</a></li> 
                    <li><a class="navigate" href="{% url 'settings' %}">Settings</a></li>
                    <li><a class="navigate" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

It looks fine on large screens. When I minimize or access it on my phone, the navbar-collapse items disappear from their regular position (as they're supposed to), and I can hover over the right side of the navbar where the button is supposed to be and my mouse pointer changes accordingly, but when I click, nothing happens. Also their is no button icon. The mouse pointer just changes as if it is hovering over a button.

Here is the header HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">  
    <title>Title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
```

Anyone have any suggestions? Am I supposed to include something involving JavaScript? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are only including the CSS - You need to also include the jQuery library - ( Bootstrap uses jquery to manipulate the dom) and the actual Bootstrap.js file

```
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```